# Attaching Build Number for binaries in Maven

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I am running maven build and storing files in Artifactory. One issue I am  facing is when ever I try a -snapshot version it overwrites the binary in Artifactory. I tried using the  Maven build number plugin, but running in to issues.I reffered to this 
http://blog.codehangover.com/track-every-build-number-with-maven/

Describing below What I did?

1. Updated the masterpom.xml with following line.

   ```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
                <executions>
                      <execution>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>create</goal>
                       </goals>
                      </execution>
                </executions>
                      <configuration>
                           <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                           <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                           <format>${version}.{0,number}</format>
                           <items>
                              <item>buildNumber</item>
                           </items>
                      </configuration>
           </plugin>
   ```
2. Now I update the pom of ear and webproject as below

   ```
                    <build>
                      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
                    </build>
   ```

When I ran mvn clean install, ear and war got generated but when i checked the war inside the ear I am finding it as some thing like war-1.0-SNAPSHOT-null.war. I believe the war and ear couldn't get the buildNumber parameter. I was able to successfully generate the buildNUmber.property files and was able to increment the number by running the buildnumber:create plugin. Here are my questions

1. What I am doing wrong here and why the buildNumber parameter is not picked.
2. Also I want to generate all the binaries including jars in the following format binary-version-Snapshot.${buildNumber}. So Do i need to update pom of each file or any other way to update this?
3. Also we are using Hudson builds for Continous Integration and we want to separate developers builds with Hudson Build number. How can we achieve this if we don't want to checkin the buildNumber.properties after the Hudson build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unique snapshots use the uniqueVersion flag (see [James Lorenzen's Blog](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-effectively-use-snapshot.html)). If you use the maven goal deploy:deploy-file the uniqueVersion flag is true by default. At my company we have the following policy. Only "official" snapshots go to the repository. A "official" snapshot is one that was build on our reference system (our Jenkins ci server). We don't need the unique feature for snapshots, since we let Jenkins archive the artifacts. This way we can always go back to a certain version if we would like too by using Jenkins. If the build breaks the snapshot will not be deployed to the repo.

To your 2nd question; my understanding is that you need to update every pom file. But since it is a one time change, it shouldn't be too much of a burden.

I am not completely understanding your 3rd question ("... separate developers builds with Hudson Build number..."). In case you want to add the build number for every build done by Hudson, you have several options.

1. You can add a string as classifier while deploying. Maven will add that classifier in the filename (artifactID-version-classifier.jar - e.g. my.company.calendar-0.0.1-Snapshot-Hudson.jar). The artifact will be retrieved by adding the classifier to the dependency.
2. add another parameter to your maven call - outputfilename (${project.build.finalName}, see [maven docu](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#outputFileName))
3. changing your version string to something like